# TableView NullPointerException on getOuterView Titanium 7.0.1 Android

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I have a news application on Titanium that was working fine on SDK 6.
Since the update to SDK 7.0.1, I am facing a NullPointerException on Android.

The application works as follows. At launch, a list of news is displayed (TableView). When I click on an item, a new windows is opened to display the news details.
When I go back, the list is displayed. Now as soon as I try to scroll the screen, the application crashes.

Bellow are the logs I have on booth Genymotion and real devices running Android 6 or 7.

```
09:38:48 E TiApplication : (main) [6538,99229] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.getOuterView()' on a null object reference; Titanium 7.0.1,2017/12/18 10:42,undefined
09:38:48 E TiApplication : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiUIView.getOuterView()' on a null object reference
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.createControls(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:244)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.setRowData(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:423)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableViewRowProxyItem.setRowData(TiTableViewRowProxyItem.java:86)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tableview.TiTableView$TTVListAdapter.getView(TiTableView.java:254)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2372)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:750)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5232)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.ListView.trackMotionScroll(ListView.java:1971)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3581)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3990)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3815)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.listview.TiNestedListView.onTouchEvent(TiNestedListView.java:127)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11721)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2955)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2961)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:445)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1828)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3292)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:407)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:11960)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4776)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4590)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4331)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6616)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6577)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6745)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6716)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6768)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:652)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
09:38:48 E TiApplication : at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this error with an example app where you just add relevant TableView code? If so it would be good to file an issue at the bug tracker (http://jira.appcelerator.org/) or have a look at this issue: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5164. Inside the comments they have the same error. 
Otherwise please show some code, that would help to solve the issue.

Comment: I have requested an account on jira. I have a working sample that reproduces the issue. I will post the details on jira as soon as I have access.

Comment: I have created the issue on JIRA with all the details: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5503